# global and $_SESSION variables with the same name are the same

Tags: php

I got a piece of code:

```
$_SESSION['cms_lang'] = 2;
global $cms_lang;
$cms_lang[1] = 'en';
```

Error:

```
Cannot use a scalar value as an array
```

Problem is that, I really don't know why server sees my global variable as the same as $_SESSION variable. I used this piece of code a couple of times and never had problem with that. I guess it must depends of settings on server. Can anyone know **how to force server to not take global and session variables with the same name as the same**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may read up on the PHP configuration setting [register_globals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals) which enables this behavior.

Also, [read about why you should disable it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) (and generally, upgrade your PHP version!)

Comment: php_flag register_globals off in .htaccess helped. I'm uploading site on client server and upgrading php version is really not on my side. But you saved me o lot of time with this! Thanks! :)